# expect(str1).to.equal(str2) passes even when str1 is not equal to str2

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, bdd, chai

I need to reverse the order of "objects" in json files of very specific format.

I wrote a test to compare the expectedResult with the actual result.

The test `expect(result).to.equal(expectedResult);`  is passing even though they have different values. I confirmed this by logging both variables to the console. 
Why does this happen?

VALUE OF STRING RESULT

```
"result": [
   {
      "courses_dept": "math",
      "courses_avg": 77.00
   },
  {
      "courses_dept": "epse",
      "courses_avg": 88.50
  },
  {
      "courses_dept": "math",
      "courses_avg": 93.00
  },
  {
      "courses_dept": "epse",
      "courses_avg": 92.19
  }
    ]
```

VALUE OF STRING EXPECTED RESULT:

```
"result": [
    {
        "courses_dept": "epse",
        "courses_avg": 92.19
    },
    {
        "courses_dept": "math",
        "courses_avg": 93.00
    },
    {
      "courses_dept": "epse",
      "courses_avg": 88.50
    },
    {
        "courses_dept": "math",
        "courses_avg": 77.00
    }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code.

```
describe("reversify", () => {
  it("Should reverse file", ()=> {
      let result = "";
      let expectedResult = "";

      try{
        let resultPromise = reversify("./test/json_files/inputs/t1.json");
        let expectedResultPromise = readJsonFile("./test/json_files/outputs/t1.json");

        //AS OF NOW THIS JUST READS THE FILE, HENCE TEST SHOULD FAIL
        resultPromise.then((data) =>{
            console.log('Result is: ', data);
            result = JSON.stringify(data);
        });

        expectedResultPromise.then(data => {
            expectedResult = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log("Expected Result is: ",data);
        });

      } catch(err) {
        throw (err);
      } finally {
          expect(result).to.equal(expectedResult);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Comparison happens synchronously before file reading finishes, so it compares empty strings which are equal. You need to `await` those promises to wait till file reading finishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `expect` statement will get executed before resolving the promise making the value of both `result` and `expectedResult` equal to `""` at the time of execution. You can use `await` to wait for the promise to get resolved.